# Python XLWT adjusting column widths

Tags: python, xlwt

I am enormously impressed with the ease of use of XLWT, but there is one thing I have not figured out how to do.  I am trying to adjust certain rows to the minimum width they would need to display all characters (in other words, what excel would do if you double clicked on the divider between cells).

I know how to adjust the column widths to a predetermined amount, but I am not certain how to determine the minimum width needed to display everything.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929115/python-xlwt-accessing-existing-cell-content-auto-adjust-column-width

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Width is 1/256 the width of the zero character for the default font. A good enough approximation is:

```
def get_width(num_characters):
    return int((1+num_characters) * 256)
```

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what I was hoping for, but as you said it works well enough for all practical purposes.

Comment: It did satisfy my requirement! Thank you so much :)