# Python : open csv files from a list and convert them into xls

Tags: python, csv, xls

I'd like to open multiple csv files from a list and then convert them into xls files.

I made that code :

```
import sys, csv, xlwt

files = ['/home/julien/excel/csv/ABORD2.csv']

for i in files:
    f=open(i, 'rb')
    g = csv.reader ((f), delimiter=";")
    workbook=xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet= xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

    for rowi, row in enumerate(g):
        for coli, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowi,coli,value)
        workbook.save(i + ".xls")
```

My xls files are created.But in both of them I only have the path of the xls.
For example for the file ABORD.xls only the following expression is written :

```
'/home/julien/excel/csv/ABORD2.xls'
```

Would you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Your code, at first glance, looks correct to me. Moreover, there is *no* variable in the example code you give here that would ever be equal to `'/home/julien/excel/csv/ABORD2.xls'`; only `'/home/julien/excel/csv/ABORD2.csv.xls'`.

Comment: Actually it works ! And yes you're right, I forgot to rename correctly the xls. Thank you Martijn !

Answer (score 4):

Sir, you're creating two Workbooks unnecessairly and you're saving the workbook with wrong identation

```
import csv, xlwt

files = ['test.csv']

for i in files:
    f=open(i, 'rb')
    g = csv.reader ((f), delimiter=";")
    wbk= xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wbk.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

    for rowi, row in enumerate(g):
        for coli, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowi,coli,value)

    wbk.save(i + '.xls')
```

Comment: The indentation works pretty well. But thank you for the help !

Comment: Worked for me as well. I easily modified it to output a single Excel file with multiple worksheets in it - initialized the workbook once, outside of the for loop and created differently-named sheets inside of the loop. I used this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9137934/1317713 to auto-adjust column width.