# Simulate autofit column in xslxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I would like to simulate the Excel autofit function in Python's xlsxwriter.  According to this url, it is not directly supported:
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html

However, it should be quite straightforward to loop through each cell on the sheet and determine the maximum size for the column and just use worksheet.set_column(row, col, width) to set the width.

The complications that is keeping me from just writing this are:

1. That URL does not specify what the units are for the third argument to set_column.
2. I can not find a way to measure the width of the item that I want to insert into the cell.
3. xlsxwriter does not appear to have a method to read back a particular cell.  This means I need to keep track of each cell width as I write the cell.  It would be better if I could just loop through all the cells, that way a generic routine could be written.

Comment: Trying to set an auto-width is not so straightforward. Glyph widths depend on the font. And what if you are writing equations into a cell? Then you cannot tell the width of a cell based on what you write into it. The units are arbitrary, that is true, but there is an actual definition! One unit approximates the width of one character in the default font. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214123

Comment: Related question regarding xlwt (the overall approach would be the same for XlsxWriter; though you'd probably want the widths for Calibri 11 instead of Arial 10): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929115/python-xlwt-accessing-existing-cell-content-auto-adjust-column-width/23946840

Answer (score 91, accepted):

[NOTE: as of Jan 2023 xslxwriter added a new method called autofit.  See jmcnamara's answer below]

As a general rule, you want the width of the columns a bit larger than the size of the longest string in the column. The with of 1 unit of the xlsxwriter columns is about equal to the width of one character. So, you can simulate autofit by setting each column to the max number of characters in that column.

Per example, I tend to use the code below when working with pandas dataframes and xlsxwriter.

It first finds the maximum width of the index, which is always the left column for a pandas to excel rendered dataframe. Then, it returns the maximum of all values and the column name for each of the remaining columns moving left to right.

It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt this code for whatever data you are using.

```
def get_col_widths(dataframe):
    # First we find the maximum length of the index column   
    idx_max = max([len(str(s)) for s in dataframe.index.values] + [len(str(dataframe.index.name))])
    # Then, we concatenate this to the max of the lengths of column name and its values for each column, left to right
    return [idx_max] + [max([len(str(s)) for s in dataframe[col].values] + [len(col)]) for col in dataframe.columns]

for i, width in enumerate(get_col_widths(dataframe)):
    worksheet.set_column(i, i, width)
```

Comment: What is metrics?

Comment: sorry metrics was the name of the dataframe. updated answer to say dataframe for clarity.

Comment: _"you want the width of the columns a bit larger than the size of the longest string in the column."_ What I do is take the maximum length in characters, and multiply it by **1.25**. Seems to work about right in most cases.

Comment: Using @DanLenski 's logic, this is what I've used: `widths = [len(col) * 1.5 if len(col) > 25 else 25 for col in cols]`. This allows you to set a minimum width.  Mine is based on column heading lengths, but adapt as you like.

Comment: This only works if you don't have a MultiIndex on your dataframe, just fyi.

Comment: is it possible to provide full piece of code for the above?

Answer (score 29):

**Update from January 2023.**

XlsxWriter 3.0.6+ now supports a [`autofit()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#autofit) worksheet method:

```py
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('autofit.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Write some worksheet data to demonstrate autofitting.
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Foo")
worksheet.write(1, 0, "Food")
worksheet.write(2, 0, "Foody")
worksheet.write(3, 0, "Froody")

worksheet.write(0, 1, 12345)
worksheet.write(1, 1, 12345678)
worksheet.write(2, 1, 12345)

worksheet.write(0, 2, "Some longer text")

worksheet.write(0, 3, "http://ww.google.com")
worksheet.write(1, 3, "https://github.com")

# Autofit the worksheet.
worksheet.autofit()

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Or using Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':    ['China',    'India',    'United States', 'Indonesia'],
    'Population': [1404338840, 1366938189, 330267887,       269603400],
    'Rank':       [1,          2,          3,               4]})

# Order the columns if necessary.
df = df[['Rank', 'Country', 'Population']]

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_autofit.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

worksheet.autofit()

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Caveat with `autofit()`. If you use another function where you supplied `None` as the width, this function crashes. (As of Feb 2023)

Comment: @Nelson that issue is fixed in version 3.0.8 of XlsxWriter.

Comment: Released 6 hours ago :D

Comment: @Nelson As soon as I saw your bug report. :-)

Comment: It seems that the autofit is not working properly for a column of URLs. The column width is then set to the header and to the length of the URLs.

Comment: @JohnDoe There are limitations to `autofit()` since it is a simulated fitting (see the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#autofit)). However URLs should work as shown in this example from the docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_autofit.html Maybe open another question or a bug report.

Comment: Additionally to autofit, How can we set a max width so that if a column is too large, it would not exceed that fixed max width value ?

Answer (score 10):

I agree with Cole Diamond. I needed to do something very similar, it worked fine for me. where self.columns is my list of columns

```
def set_column_width(self):
    length_list = [len(x) for x in self.columns]
    for i, width in enumerate(length_list):
        self.worksheet.set_column(i, i, width)
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to use your code with the one above. Can you help me out?

Comment: sure, ask a question, post the link. and I will answer it.

Answer (score 10):

> That URL does not specify what the units are for the third argument to set_column.

The column widths are given in multiples of the width of the '0' character in the font Calibri, size 11 (that's the Excel standard).

> I can not find a way to measure the width of the item that I want to insert into the cell.

In order to get a handle on the exact width of a string, you can use `tkinter`'s ability to measure string lengths in pixels, depending on the font/size/weight/etc. If you define a font, e.g.

```
reference_font = tkinter.font.Font(family='Calibri', size=11)
```

you can afterwards use its `measure` method to determine string widths in pixels, e.g.

```
reference_font.measure('This is a string.')
```

In order to do this for a cell from your Excel table, you need to take its format into account (it contains all the information on the used font). That means, if you wrote something to your table using `worksheet.write(row, col, cell_string, format)`, you can get the used font like this:

```
used_font = tkinter.font.Font(family     = format.font_name,
                              size       = format.font_size,
                              weight     = ('bold' if format.bold else 'normal'),
                              slant      = ('italic' if format.italic else 'roman'),
                              underline  = format.underline,
                              overstrike = format.font_strikeout)
```

and afterwards determine the cell width as

```
cell_width = used_font.measure(cell_string+' ')/reference_font.measure('0')
```

The whitespace is added to the string to provide some margin. This way the results are actually very close to Excel's autofit results, so that I assume Excel is doing just that.

For the `tkinter` magic to work, a `tkinter.Tk()` instance (a window) has to be open, therefore the full code for a function that returns the required width of a cell would look like this:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font

def get_cell_width(cell_string, format = None):
  root = tkinter.Tk()
  reference_font = tkinter.font.Font(family='Calibri', size=11)
  if format:
    used_font = tkinter.font.Font(family     = format.font_name,
                                  size       = format.font_size,
                                  weight     = ('bold' if format.bold else 'normal'),
                                  slant      = ('italic' if format.italic else 'roman'),
                                  underline  = format.underline,
                                  overstrike = format.font_strikeout)
  else:
    used_font = reference_font
  cell_width = used_font.measure(cell_string+' ')/reference_font.measure('0')
  root.update_idletasks()
  root.destroy()
  return cell_width
```

Of course you would like to get the `root` handling and reference font creation out of the function, if it is meant to be executed frequently. Also, it might be faster to use a lookup table format->font for your workbook, so that you do not have to define the used font every single time.

Finally, one could take care of line breaks within the cell string:

```
pixelwidths = (used_font.measure(part) for part in cell_string.split('\n'))
cell_width = (max(pixelwidths) + used_font.measure(' '))/reference_font.measure('0')
```

Also, if you are using the Excel filter function, the dropdown arrow symbol needs another 18 pixels (at 100% zoom in Excel). And there might be merged cells spanning multiple columns... A lot of room for improvements!

> xlsxwriter does not appear to have a method to read back a particular cell. This means I need to keep track of each cell width as I write the cell. It would be better if I could just loop through all the cells, that way a generic routine could be written.

If you do not like to keep track within your own data structure, there are at least three ways to go:

(A) Register a write handler to do the job:
You can register a write handler for all standard types. In the handler function, you simply pass on the write command, but also do the bookkeeping wrt. column widths. This way, you only need to read and set the optimal column width in the end (before closing the `workbook`).

```
# add worksheet attribute to store column widths
worksheet.colWidths = [0]*number_of_used_columns
# register write handler
for stdtype in [str, int, float, bool, datetime, timedelta]:
  worksheet.add_write_handler(stdtype, colWidthTracker)


def colWidthTracker(sheet, row, col, value, format):
  # update column width
  sheet.colWidths[col] = max(sheet.colWidths[col], get_cell_width(value, format))
  # forward write command
  if isinstance(value, str):
    if value == '':
      sheet.write_blank(row, col, value, format)
    else:
      sheet.write_string(row, col, value, format)
  elif isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, float):
    sheet.write_number(row, col, value, format)
  elif isinstance(value, bool):
    sheet.write_boolean(row, col, value, format)
  elif isinstance(value, datetime) or isinstance(value, timedelta):
    sheet.write_datetime(row, col, value, format)
  else:
    raise TypeError('colWidthTracker cannot handle this type.')


# and in the end...
for col in columns_to_be_autofitted:    
  worksheet.set_column(col, col, worksheet.colWidths[col])
```

(B) Use [karolyi's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53091320/13726558) to go through the data stored within XlsxWriter's internal variables. However, this is [discouraged by the module's author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62865195/python-xlsxwriter-extract-value-from-cell/63251349#comment111848986_63251349), since it might break in future releases.

(C) Follow the [recommendation of jmcnamara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62865195/python-xlsxwriter-extract-value-from-cell/63251349#comment111880172_63251349): Inherit from and override the default worksheet class and add in some autofit code, like this example: [xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_inheritance2.html](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_inheritance2.html)

Comment: Good work on this. It might be worth rolling some of this work up into a working example for inclusion in the XlsxWriter examples directory. Based on option A or C. If you open an issue/feature request on Github we can discuss it there.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer.  One of the most useful in my recent memory!  I used all of the tips in the answer.  I followed style (C) as recommended.  Regarding the nice tip about "dropdown arrow symbol needs another 18 pixels (at 100% zoom in Excel)", I adjusted the width of auto-filter columns by adding: `(18 / (64 / 8.43))`.  I am using vanilla (default) fonts, so default column width is 8.43 or 64 pixels.

Answer (score 7):

I recently ran into this same issue and this is what I came up with:

```
r = 0
c = 0
for x in list:
    worksheet.set_column('{0}:{0}'.format(chr(c + ord('A'))), len(str(x)) + 2)
    worksheet.write(r, c, x)
    c += 1
```

In my example `r` would be the row number you are outputting to, `c` would be the column number you are outputting to (both 0 indexed), and `x` would be the value from `list` that you are wanting to be in the cell.

the `'{0}:{0}'.format(chr(c + ord('A')))` piece takes the column number provided and converts it to the column letter accepted by xlsxwriter, so if `c = 0` `set_column` would see `'A:A'`, if `c = 1` then it would see `'B:B'`, and so on.

the `len(str(x)) + 2` piece determines the length of the string you are trying to output then adds 2 to it to ensure that the excel cell is wide enough as the length of the string does not exactly correlate to the width of the cell. You may want to play with rather you add `2` or possibly more depending on your data.

The units that xlsxwriter accepts is a little harder to explain. When you are in excel and you hover over where you can change the column width you will see `Width: 8.43 (64 pixels)`. In this example the unit it accepts is the `8.43`, which I think is centimeters? But excel does not even provide a unit, at least not explicitly.

**Note:** I have only tried this answer on excel files that contain 1 row of data. If you will have multiple rows, you will need to have a way to determine which row will have the 'longest' information and only apply this to that row. But if each column will be roughly the same size regardless of row, then this should work fine for you.

Good luck and I hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

[Cole Diamond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463274/simulate-autofit-column-in-xslxwriter/37218180#37218180) is awesome. I just updated the subroutine to handle multiindex rows and columns.

```
def get_col_widths(dataframe):
    # First we find the maximum length of the index columns   
    idx_max = [max([len(str(s)) for s in dataframe.index.get_level_values(idx)] + [len(str(idx))]) for idx in dataframe.index.names]
    # Then, we concatenate this to the max of the lengths of column name and its values for each column, left to right
    return idx_max + [max([len(str(s)) for s in dataframe[col].values] + \
                          [len(str(x)) for x in col] if dataframe.columns.nlevels > 1 else [len(str(col))]) for col in dataframe.columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another workaround to simulate Autofit that I've found on the [Github site of xlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/323). I've modified it to return the approximate size of horizontal text (column width) or 90° rotated text (row height):

```
from PIL import ImageFont

def get_cell_size(value, font_name, font_size, dimension="width"):
    """ value: cell content
        font_name: The name of the font in the target cell
        font_size: The size of the font in the target cell """
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_name, size=font_size)
    (size, h) = font.getsize(str(value))
    if dimension == "height":
        return size * 0.92   # fit value experimentally determined
    return size * 0.13       # fit value experimentally determined
```

This doesn't address bold text or other format elements that might affect the text size. Otherwise it works pretty well.

To find the width for your columns for autofit:

```
def get_col_width(data, font_name, font_size, min_width=1):
    """ Assume 'data' to be an iterable (rows) of iterables (columns / cells)
    Also, every cell is assumed to have the same font and font size.
    Returns a list with the autofit-width per column """
    colwidth = [min_width for col in data[0]]
    for x, row in enumerate(data):
        for y, value in enumerate(row):
            colwidth[y] = max(colwidth[y], get_cell_size(value, font_name, font_size))
    return colwidth
```

Answer (score 3):

My version that will go over the one worksheet and autoset the field lengths:

```
from typing import Optional
from xlsxwriter.worksheet import (
    Worksheet, cell_number_tuple, cell_string_tuple)


def get_column_width(worksheet: Worksheet, column: int) -> Optional[int]:
    """Get the max column width in a `Worksheet` column."""
    strings = getattr(worksheet, '_ts_all_strings', None)
    if strings is None:
        strings = worksheet._ts_all_strings = sorted(
            worksheet.str_table.string_table,
            key=worksheet.str_table.string_table.__getitem__)
    lengths = set()
    for row_id, colums_dict in worksheet.table.items():  # type: int, dict
        data = colums_dict.get(column)
        if not data:
            continue
        if type(data) is cell_string_tuple:
            iter_length = len(strings[data.string])
            if not iter_length:
                continue
            lengths.add(iter_length)
            continue
        if type(data) is cell_number_tuple:
            iter_length = len(str(data.number))
            if not iter_length:
                continue
            lengths.add(iter_length)
    if not lengths:
        return None
    return max(lengths)


def set_column_autowidth(worksheet: Worksheet, column: int):
    """
    Set the width automatically on a column in the `Worksheet`.
    !!! Make sure you run this function AFTER having all cells filled in
    the worksheet!
    """
    maxwidth = get_column_width(worksheet=worksheet, column=column)
    if maxwidth is None:
        return
    worksheet.set_column(first_col=column, last_col=column, width=maxwidth)
```

just call `set_column_autowidth` with the column.

Comment: How do we use your code given our data is in a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the solutions given here were too elaborate for the rather simple thing that I was looking for: every column had to be sized so that all its values fits nicely. So I wrote my own solution. It basically iterates over all columns, and for each column it gets all string values (including the column name itself) and then takes the longest string as the maximal width for that column.

```py
# Set the width of the columns to the max. string length in that column
# ~ simulates Excel's "autofit" functionality
for col_idx, colname in enumerate(df.columns):
    max_width = max([len(colname)]+[len(str(s)) for s in df[colname]])
    worksheet.set_column(col_idx, col_idx, max_width+1)  # + 1 to add some padding
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of code that supports MultiIndex for row and column - it is not pretty but works for me. It expands on @cole-diamond answer:

```
def _xls_make_columns_wide_enough(dataframe, worksheet, padding=1.1, index=True):
    def get_col_widths(dataframe, padding, index):
        max_width_idx = []
        if index and isinstance(dataframe.index, pd.MultiIndex):
            # Index name lengths
            max_width_idx = [len(v) for v in dataframe.index.names]

            # Index value lengths
            for column, content in enumerate(dataframe.index.levels):
                max_width_idx[column] = max(max_width_idx[column],
                                            max([len(str(v)) for v in content.values]))
        elif index:
            max_width_idx = [
                max([len(str(s))
                     for s in dataframe.index.values] + [len(str(dataframe.index.name))])
            ]

        if isinstance(dataframe.columns, pd.MultiIndex):
            # Take care of columns - headers first.
            max_width_column = [0] * len(dataframe.columns.get_level_values(0))
            for level in range(len(dataframe.columns.levels)):
                values = dataframe.columns.get_level_values(level).values
                max_width_column = [
                    max(v1, len(str(v2))) for v1, v2 in zip(max_width_column, values)
                ]

            # Now content.
            for idx, col in enumerate(dataframe.columns):
                max_width_column[idx] = max(max_width_column[idx],
                                            max([len(str(v)) for v in dataframe[col].values]))

        else:
            max_width_column = [
                max([len(str(s)) for s in dataframe[col].values] + [len(col)])
                for col in dataframe.columns
            ]

        return [round(v * padding) for v in max_width_idx + max_width_column]

    for i, width in enumerate(get_col_widths(dataframe, padding, index)):
        worksheet.set_column(i, i, width)
```

Comment: I found this solution simpler and worked when looping through multiple dataframes:  for idx, col in enumerate(firm.columns[:-1]):  #stopped before last column because of its content and I needed to wrap just that column
            max_len = firm[col].map(lambda x: len(x)).max()  #gets length of longest string
            worksheet.set_column(idx, idx, max_len+4) #sets the column to the length of the longest string + 4 to ensure it all fits, excel issue I presume

Answer (score 1):

Openpyxl easily handles this task. Just install the module and insert the below line of code in your file
# Imorting the necessary modules
try:
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
except ImportError:
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

```
for column_cells in sheet.columns:
    new_column_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    new_column_letter = (get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
    if new_column_length > 0:
        sheet.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23
```