# adjust the width of the excel cell using python

Tags: python, html, excel

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
writer = ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')
parta.to_excel(writer,index=False)
writer.save()
```

[This is the current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHA76.png)

[This is the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUYkv.png)

How do I adjust the width of the excel cell to see all the words clearly using python?

I tried other methods which i saw on stackoverflow but they didn't work for me. An example is trying 'ws.Columns.AutoFit()' but I received an error saying
AttributeError: '_XlsxWriter' object has no attribute 'Columns'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust cell width in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665865/adjust-cell-width-in-excel)

Comment: @ShivamMishra Hi, I tried that method but sadly it didn't work for me

Comment: Checkout my answer on how to use set_column method(given in the mentioned answer) for your case.

Answer (score 5):

To use [set_column](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#set_column) method, you need to have your worksheet object. Take a look at this it will make the size of the cells entered to 50:

```
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')
parta.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.set_column(1, 2, 50)
writer.save()
```

> Parameters of the set_column() method: first_col, last_col, width,
>   format(optional),options(optional)

Additionally, you could do something like:

```
width = len("your text")
worksheet.set_column(1, 2, 50)
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you found it useful, please accept my answer by clicking the tick mark ;)