# Change column width of existing tab in excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have dataframe (df) that is added to an existing excel file as a new tab ('Print'). I am having difficulties adjusting the column width any ideas?

**Code**

```
book = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Print')
worksheet = writer.sheets['Print']
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 40) #This does not work
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust cell width in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665865/adjust-cell-width-in-excel)

Comment: If you are open to changing your engine to `'xlsxwriter'`, this blog post [Improving Pandas’s Excel Output](http://pbpython.com/improve-pandas-excel-output.html) answers your question nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Print')
sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('Print')
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 40
writer.save()
```

Answer (score -2):

I've never used nor done this, but I just googled for "worksheet.set_column" and found this:
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html

The syntax for the function is

```
set_column(first_col, last_col, width, cell_format, options)
```

So I'd say the answer is:

```
worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 40)
```

Comment: OP is using `engine = 'openpyxl'` which is different than `xlsxwriter`.