# Trouble with Excel Autofit in Python (3.6)

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to autofit the columns in my python generated xlsx file.
Found the code from here[https://stackoverflow.com/a/33665967/5518944], but  getting an exception.
I am using Microsoft Office 2015.

Using this code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

ends up in following error:

```
[...]Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 236, in GetModuleForCLSID
    __import__(sub_mod_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com.gen_py.00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x8._Application'
```

Are you able to help me with this problem?

Comment: Hello, do you have MS Excel installed ?

Comment: Hi @reportgunner, yes Excel is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I can access and edit .xlsx files using:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="yourfile.xlsx")
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

etc..
```

But i'm not sure if you really need `EnsureDispatch`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127959/win32-dispatch-vs-win32-gencache-in-python-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) for mor about the differences.

Comment: I tried your code (only first two lines), but this results in the same error on my side. Maybe anything missing in my installation?

Comment: Oh. I use Python 3.7 and used pip to install `pywin32`, that is mandatory. And i work with Excel 2013, btw. People mention it could be a good idea to pip-install `pypiwin32` too, maybe worth a try?

Comment: see [here](https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-win32/127hc7eagz/new-pywin32-errors-stating-object-has-no-attribute-and-the-code-worked-previously#20120717vfbmkovr77dlld3z2xkowieu6q) , this advice to delete `\win32com\gen_py` was also in the link in this answer.