# How to use xlsxwriter to mimic autoFit row height and column width, middle align, left align and wrap text?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Excel can autofit row height and column width. It can also Middle Align, Left Align and Wrap Text.

Could anybody show me how to achieve these with xlsxwriter?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/align-text-in-a-cell-b2489a1f-6c89-45b7-9562-bbc287aa71ea

Comment: did you check documentation for xlsxwriter?

Comment: Here is the doc. I don't see which section includes the info that I need.

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

There is quite an extensive discussion of the simulated auto-fit functionality already [in the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63265507/13726558).
The alignment functions are explained in [this part of the xlsxwriter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_align).