# Dynamically adjust the widths of all columns in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter

can you help me with the column autowidth in excel. I have a data frame named "fp" and when i export it in excel, i have the following output [Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8TZ6.png). i would like to adjust automatically the width of column so that it will look like this: [Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76zAe.png).

the initial code is

`filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file to convert")`

```
fichierp = pd.read_excel(r'%s' % filename, index_col=1)
fp = fichierp.iloc[:, [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 10,13]]
```

what i have tried is:

`for column in fp:`

```
column_width = max(fp[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
col_idx = fp.columns.get_loc(column)
fp.set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)`
```

Comment: If you are able to use ````xlsxWriter```` then you can use the code available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463274/simulate-autofit-column-in-xslxwriter#:~:text=As%20a%20general%20rule%2C%20you,of%20characters%20in%20that%20column.) to adjust the column widths with ````set_column````