# how to autofit all excel columns using python

Tags: python

I am getting error when I am trying to autofit all columns. I want to autofit all columns is that possible

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter


book = load_workbook('QualityReview Business-Template.xlsx')

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('QualityReview Business-Template.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
busi_issue_date.to_excel(writer, "IssueData")
worksheet = book["IssueData"]
worksheet.Columns.AutoFit()     ---->> This is line where I get error
writer.save()
```

Error as

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_137575/2824807293.py in <module>
     17 worksheet = book["IssueData"]

---> 18 worksheet.Columns.AutoFit()



AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'Columns'
```

Comment: It's `worksheet.autofit()` and you need [`XlsxWriter 3.0.6+`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75120836/16120011) as an engine.