# Write data frame into excel with wide column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a data frame into excel like this :

```
    df = DataFrame({'Frequency':lenFreq,'Fatigue Thrust    [N]':meqThrust[iexcel],'Extreme Thrust [N]':extremeThrust[iexcel],'Extreme Thrust DMR [N]':extremeThrustDMR[iexcel],\
                'Fatigue Yaw [Nm]':meqYaw[iexcel],'Extreme Yaw [Nm]':extremeYaw[iexcel],'Extreme Flapwise [Nm]':extremeFlapwise[iexcel][ilenFreq]})

    df.to_excel(workbookOutput, sheet_name='Results', index=False)
```

but every time I open the file I need to expand columns :

[image]

I would like to know an option to expand columns automatically when writing to excel. Thanks

Comment: Pandas dev [ruled this out of scope](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4049). You may find some direction in these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929115/

Comment: Related, if not outright duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326973/is-there-a-way-to-auto-adjust-excel-column-widths-with-pandas-excelwriter (this was even mentioned in the Pandas issue tracker thread linked to by @JohnGalt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to directly re-size excel cells when you call `df.to_excel()` but here is a way to do it after that call

```py
df = DataFrame({'Frequency':lenFreq,'Fatigue Thrust    [N]':meqThrust[iexcel],'Extreme Thrust [N]':extremeThrust[iexcel],'Extreme Thrust DMR [N]':extremeThrustDMR[iexcel],\
             'Fatigue Yaw [Nm]':meqYaw[iexcel],'Extreme Yaw [Nm]':extremeYaw[iexcel],'Extreme Flapwise [Nm]':extremeFlapwise[iexcel][ilenFreq]})

df.to_excel(workbookOutput, sheet_name='Results', index=False)

sheet = workbookOutput.sheet_by_name('Results')
nrows = len(sheet.get_rows())
ncolumns = len(sheet.get_cols())

for row_index in range (nrows):
    for column_index in range(ncolumns) :
      cwidth = sheet.col(column_index).width
      column_data = sheet.cell(row_index,column_index).value
      if (len(column_data)*367) > cwidth:  
          sheet.col(column_index).width = (len(column_data)*367)
```

Comment: What's the data structure of workbookOutput? Is it a ExcelWriter?